# How to avoid Google Chrome try access my contacts when executing tests with Jbehave and Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I'm developing and executing some tests with Jbehave and Selenium WebDriver.

When one of the tests try to write into a login field, then Chrome WebDriver try to access the address book and due lack of permissions shows this message:

```
Google Chrome[424:ea03] Address book access is denied for executable at path: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

How can I avoid that the driver try to access to the Address book?

Comment: Did you ever solve this in a different way than my answer? (As an aside: I'm pretty sure that downvote is a retaliation for some unrelated Meta discussion; there was another downvote at the same time, but meanwhile that user's sock puppet has been deleted.)

Answer (score -1):

This is probably caused by Chrome's autofill.

I don't know if you can tell the driver to control that. But one can avoid Chrome from using the contacts for autofill: in its Autofill Settings disable "Include addresses from my Address Book card".